# Extracting part of a csv by a list

Tags: r

I have a .csv file like this

```
pair,S17A,S2..APOBEC.,S1..age.,S18.like,S3..BRCA.,S17B
LP2000104-DNA_A01_vs_LP2000101-DNA_A01,0.448027080410302,0,0,0,0,0.410602648202438
LP2000325-DNA_A01_vs_LP2000317-DNA_A01,0.343096214261112,0,0.111190317814775,0.171937435363758,0.187395051556141,0.156209735124657
LP2000327-DNA_A01_vs_LP2000319-DNA_A01,0.436249785689912,0,0.066118729867486,0.077392575088635,0.116384601626772,0.263251836199875
```

I have a list of samples which are a part of first column for example

```
LP6005334-DNA_H01
LP6008334-DNA_A03
LP6008334-DNA_A04
LP6008334-DNA_B02
LP6008334-DNA_C02
LP6008334-DNA_D02
LP6008336-DNA_H01
```

I want to extract .csv for this list of samples

I can not think of intersect function as these samples are a part of sample name not full name

Can you help?

Comment: As usual you do not provide example output despite in like every of your question people ask for it. No surprise you constantly get downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strsplit`.

```
ciao <- "LP2000104-DNA_A01_vs_LP2000101-DNA_A01"
sampleIneed <- "LP6008334-DNA_A03"   
sampleIneed %in% strsplit(ciao,"_vs_")[[1]]
[1] FALSE

"LP2000104-DNA_A01" %in% strsplit(ciao,"_vs_")[[1]]
[1] TRUE
```

You can loop (e.g. `sapply`or `lapply`) through the element of the first column to extract only the rows you need.

You can also simply use `grep` on the first column

```
ciao <_ your_csv
grep("LP2000104-DNA_A01", ciao$pair)
```